# sscanf("0X80.9", "%f", &value) sets value to a hex float not a float

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

I have some code that reads letter value pairs. It can be simplified as:

```
float value = 0.0;
sscanf("0X80.9", "%f", &value);
```

In Visual Studio 2013, value = 0

In Visual Studio 2015 and above, value = 128.5625  (i.e. 0x80 in hex = 128 in decimal)

Anyone know why this has changed? More importantly, anyone know how to make it work like it used to?

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++? These kind of things can depend *very much* on the language. C and C++ are *not* the same language, they are very different.

Comment: @Someprogramerdude This particular thing can't.

Comment: It seems to be reading your hexadecimal float value because you wrote a hexadecimal float value; why is it a problem?

Comment: I have tried in C & C++ and get the same results.

Comment: It is a problem as the real case is something like: "W1V0X80" etc. I want to read the 'prefix' and value into a char and associated value. The behaviour changed between two versions of compiler and indeed other compilers show various behaviours as well.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is a feature of the standard library, not the compiler. (The compiler and library versions are somewhat correlated, but the correspondence is not absolute.)

Answer (score 4):

C99 added a new feature, hexadecimal floating-point constants. It also added new formats to the `*scanf()` functions. (A hexadecimal floating-point constant in source code must have an exponent part; for `scanf`, the exponent is optional.)

`scanf` reads as much of the input as it can that's consistent with the format. For pre-1999 C, this is the initial `"0"`; the following `"X80.9"`is left. For C99, `"0X80.9"` is valid, and is converted to the floating-point value `128.5625`. (The format is the same as what's accepted by `strtof()`.)

The C++ standard includes most of the C standard library by reference. It didn't update to the C99 version of the C library until c++2012.

Most likely Visual Studio 2015 supports C++12 or later, and Visual Studio 2013 doesn't.

Since the new behavior is now standard, I suggest adapting your code to deal with it rather than trying to force the old behavior. If there's a way to make VS2015 behave in the old way, it should be documented.

Answer (score 3):

C99 adds hexadecimal floating point constants.  The `printf()` formats are `%a` and `%A`; there are the corresponding `scanf()` formats too.  But as with `%f`, `%e`, `%g`, the `scanf()` floating point formats all accept any floating point format (so `%f` can read output printed using `%e`, etc).

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 — §6.4.4.2 Floating constants
>
> *floating-constant:*
>           *decimal-floating-constant*
>           *hexadecimal-floating-constant*
>
> …
>
> *hexadecimal-floating-constant:*
>           *hexadecimal-prefix hexadecimal-fractional-constant
>   binary-exponent-part floating-suffix<sub>opt</sub>*
>           *hexadecimal-prefix hexadecimal-digit-sequence
>   binary-exponent-part floating-suffix<sub>opt</sub>*
>
> …
>
> *hexadecimal-fractional-constant:*
>           *hexadecimal-digit-sequence<sub>opt</sub>* `.`
>   *hexadecimal-digit-sequence*
>           *hexadecimal-digit-sequence* `.`
>
> *binary-exponent-part:*
>           `p` *sign<sub>opt</sub> digit-sequence*
>           `P` *sign<sub>opt</sub> digit-sequence*
>
> *hexadecimal-digit-sequence:*
>           *hexadecimal-digit*
>           *hexadecimal-digit-sequence hexadecimal-digit*
>
> *floating-suffix:* one of
>           `f` `l` `F` `L`

(The hexadecimal prefix is `0x` or `0X` of course.)

The `0X80.9` notation doesn't exactly correspond to the notation required of hexadecimal floating point constants in C source code because there is no 'binary-exponent-part', but …

1. the `scanf()` family of functions can only push back 1 character, so they can't tell there's a problem until far too late, so it ends up treating it as if there was a `P0` at the end.  The `scanf()` functions read data items according to a conversion specification:

   > An input item is read from the stream, unless the specification includes an n specifier. An
   >   input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed
   >   any specified field width and which is, or is a prefix of, a matching input sequence.285)
   >   The first character, if any, after the input item remains unread.
2. the `strtod()` family of functions accept:

   > — a `0x` or `0X`, then a nonempty sequence of hexadecimal digits optionally containing a
   >   decimal-point character, then an optional binary exponent part as defined in 6.4.4.2;
3. and the `scanf()` family of functions accept:

   > `a`, `e`, `f`, `g`
   >   Matches an optionally signed floating-point number, infinity, or NaN, whose
   >   format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtod`
   >   function. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to floating.

Comment: The standard says `scanf` recognizes the same format recognized by `strtod`, which explicitly says the exponent part is optional. It may have been motivated by 1-character pushback, but the standard doesn't say so. Similarly, `42` is not a floating-point constant, but `scanf("%f", ...")` accepts it (presumably because it would be user-hostile not to).

Comment: OK; yes, that's interesting — thanks.  I've added some extra info covering that.

Answer (score 1):

In the 1999 C Standard it was added that the input for `strtod` (which is what `%f` in scanf refers to) can include a `0x` or `0X` prefix to indicate a hex float.

16 years later it seems Microsoft have finally gotten around to doing the work.

Your best option would be to move forward with the new behaviour, rather than trying to invoke compiler flags to get the old behaviour (which may not even be possible, I don't know).

To emulate the old behaviour in your project you could use code like:

```
double my_scan(char const *s)
{
    double value = 0.0;

    if ( ! memcmp(s, "0X", 2) )
         sscanf(s, "%f", &value);

    return value;
}
```

or whatever would suit your use case. Perhaps you might end up writing your own tokenizer.