# sscanf fails to read double hex

Tags: c++, c, scanf, visual-c++-2013

I need to preserve the exact binary representation of some doubles in a text file with other ascii values, so I am using "%a" as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4740044/7098259) question.

```
fprintf (pFile, "Scale: %a, %a, %a\n", scale.x, scale.y, scale.z);
```

However, when I try to read it in with "%la" the scanf returns 0 items read.

```
double x=0, y=0, z=0;
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, pFile);
int test = sscanf (buf, "Scale: %la, %la, %la\n", &x, &y, &z);
// test is zero!
```

When I open up the debugger, I see that the string buffer is exactly as I expected it.

> buf   ... "Scale: 0x1.fc70e3p-1, 0x1.fc70e3p-1, 0x1.fc70e3p-1\n"  ...
>   char[1000]

So why can't it read it?

As requested by [Nate Eldredge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredge), here is my MCVE version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double x=0, y=0, z=0;
    const char* buf = "Scale: 0x1.fc70e3p-1, 0x1.fc70e3p-1, 0x1.fc70e3p-1\n";
    int test = sscanf(buf, "Scale: %la , %la , %la", &x, &y, &z);
    // test is zero!
}
```

Note: I am using MS Visual Studio 2013

Second Note:  I need to send the source code and data files to a third party, who has his own compiler. So the save format has to be relatively platform-independent.

Comment: The code seems to work for me.  Can you make an [mcve]?

Comment: I am not sure this is related, but shouldn't you nul-terminate `buf`?

Comment: `fgets` stops at EOL or `\0`  So it's dependent on the data stored go read correctly.

Comment: Specifically, [this code](https://pastebin.com/qcRgef9V) outputs `0.993049, 0.993049, 0.993049` which seems to be right.

Comment: @NateEldredge I posted the MCVE and added a note about my compiler

Comment: ok, I posted the entire main.cpp as requested @NateEldredge and I'd be grateful if you undo your close vote if that was you

Comment: It wasn't me, I don't have enough reputation to cast close votes.  One thing I noticed, the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/scanf-width-specification?view=vs-2019 does not actually say that `%la` is allowed...

Comment: Just as a guess, if you change `%la` to `%lf`, what happens?  I think the standard says that all of `aeEfFgG` are supposed to behave identically for `scanf`, including the handling of hex floats (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).  The MS documentation I linked above doesn't mention handling hex floats with `f`, but maybe it will work anyway...

Comment: This code [works on gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3mFxZf49Pobly5cG). This code [works on clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vHmtuZPGNBwVeYAC).

Comment: Possible Duplicate [sscanf(“0X80.9”, “%f”, &value) sets value to a hex float not a float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47464440/sscanf0x80-9-f-value-sets-value-to-a-hex-float-not-a-float) about VS13

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks, although that one is trying to get 2013 behavior in 2015, whereas I am trying to get 2015 behavior in 2013. I am kinda shocked that they still had not implemented a compliant `strtod` in 2013. Now what? Write it myself?

Comment: The challenge is that your hex values are hex-float values, otherwise if they were simply hex, you could read as unsigned long and then use a union between double and unsigned long. With the hexfloat format you will have to piece it together yourself. Presumably the information can be translated into a sign-bit, a biased exponent and normalized mantissa. At that point it is just a matter of shifting bits.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin by "union" you mean something equivalent to a reinterpret_cast, right? I need to send the source code and data files to a third party, who has his own compiler. And I assume I would lose platform-compatibility if I reinterpreted the double from raw bytes.

Comment: @PatrickParker Isn't it shocking that Microsoft doesn't want to make a *C* compiler for their platform <3

Comment: @PatrickParker yes that is the basic gest, but use of a `union` is the way provided by the C standard to avoid the *strict aliasing* violation. You generally want to avoid a direct cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft VS2013 `strtod`, `sscanf`, and `istringstream`, etc. did **not** implement the c99 c++11 standard and they **cannot** parse hex floats or hex doubles.

- Related Bug Report:

  https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/6349